# How would I correct this code so the the slide animation I want to use works on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am brand new to this topic at uni and I am a big amateur. This code is puzzling me and I must be going wrong with the keyframe section and the webkit.

Here is my HTML piece of code:

```
<div class="stage">
<figure class="ball"></figure>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS i want to animate the ball.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
0% {
left: 0;
top: 0;
  }

50% {
left: 244px;
top: 100px;
}

100% {
left: 488px;
top: 0;
 }
}

.stage {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 6px;
border: solid 1px #551A8B;
height: 150px;
position: relative;
min-width: 538px;
margin-top:50px;
}

.stage:hover .ball {
animation: slide 2s ease-in-out .5s infinite alternate;
}

.ball {
background: #551A8B;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css `animation`, on some browsers, may need a vendor prefix. In your case, you have indeed used the `-webkit-` prefix. But when it is used, you need to set it on both `@keyframe` and `animation`:

*Many developers prefer to set both vendor and vendorless properties*

[**See here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcLah1k6/):

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    ...
}

.stage:hover .ball {
    -webkit-animation: slide 2s ease-in-out .5s infinite alternate;
```

You were setting the prefix on `keyframe`, but not on `animation`